# How to convert MySQL query to Eloquent Relationships?

Tags: relationship, laravel-5.7

I don't really know what words or terms I would search. I have also read the documentation in laravel 5.7, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations.

But still I couldn't find the thing that I want.

**The result that I am expecting is this in MySQL:**

```
SELECT id as product_id, (SELECT name FROM products WHERE id = transactions.product_id), created_at FROM transactions WHERE user_id = 1
```

**This is the result of the mysql query:**
[image]

I already have a model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transactions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'product_id'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Products')->select('name');
    }
}
?>
```

Then in my controller:

```
public function transactions()
{
    $transactions = new Transactions::where('user_id',Auth::id())->product;
    return view('transactions', ['transactions' => $transactions]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `belongsTo()` relation. Transaction belongs to one product, product has many transactions.

Also, you can (or better should) rename model to a singlular. Then you don't need to use `protected $table`.

It is not necessarily to select only `name`.

Transaction model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'product_id'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function transactions()
{
    $transactions = Transaction::with('product')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->get();

    return view('transactions', ['transactions' => $transactions]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    echo $transaction->product_id; //attribute product_id of transaction
    echo $transaction->product->id; //attribute id of product
    echo $transaction->product->name;  //attribute name of product
@endforeach
```